# How to resolve Storybook error "Expecting an HTML snippet or DOM node from the story"?

Tags: node.js, storybook, twing

Can anyone help me resolve this Storybook error "Expecting an HTML snippet or DOM node from the story"?

[image]

I am integrating this into Drupal, so I'm using twig files and the twing module.

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.16",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16",
"@storybook/addons": "^6.5.16",
"@storybook/html": "^6.5.16",
"@storybook/theming": "^6.5.16",
"@whitespace/storybook-addon-html": "^5.1.6",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
"drupal-attribute": "^1.0.2",
"node-sass": "^9.0.0",
"node-sass-magic-importer": "^5.3.3",
"twing": "^5.2.2",
"twing-loader": "^4.0.1"}
```

And my story is very simple just for testing:

```
export default { title: 'Blocks' };
import block from './block.twig';
export const Default = () => {
  const output = block();
  console.log(output);
  return output;
};
```

Here is my block.twig file — again very simple just for testing:

```
<div>BLOCK</div>
```

And here's my main.js

```
const path = require('path');

const stories = ['../../components/_patterns/**/*.story.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx)'];

const addons = [];

const webpackFinal = config => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.twig$/,
    loader: 'twing-loader',
    options: {
      environmentModulePath: path.resolve(`${__dirname}/environment.js`),
    },
  });

  return {
    ...config,
    resolve: {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        '@dist': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist'),
      },
    },
  };
};

module.exports = {
  stories,
  addons,
  webpackFinal,
  features: {
    postcss: false,
  },
};
```

I run `start-storybook -p 3000 -c storybook/.storybook` to build then `start-storybook -p 3000 -c storybook/.storybook` to run Storybook.

I'm running Node v16.20.2. I was on Node v13 but I switched to 16 to try to resolve this error, but to no avail!

Does anyone have any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: The issue appears to be with Twing. I've since switched to Twig.js and I have my stories rendering correctly. However, I would prefer to stick with Twing.